# How can I make a basic BlueTooth communication between a cellphone and MXCHIP EMC3080-P module?

Tags: uart, communication, bluetooth-low-energy, at-commands, module

I'm trying to use the EMC3080-P module from MXCHIP, because it's used in some applications from ST, the company where I had the microcontroller I'm using (for example, the B-U585I-IOT02A discovery kit for IoT), and as I can see in the specifications, it has a lot of functionalities, including BLE, Wifi connection, UART, AT command support, MQTT, etc. I'm using the chip only, without any developer board provided by MXCHIP.

The connections I made where only the power source at pins 16 and 17, the UART RX (pin 13) and TX (pin 14), and the pin 19 (PA20) to 3.3V to enter in the APP mode.

[image]

[image]

However, the documentation about this product is very poor in practical therms. It says briefly "how", in theory, but it doesn't show you any example where I can see a real communication. I could satisfactorily made a UART communication between the module and the PC by a USB UART addapter, and now I have the latest version of it (A247):

[image]

Besides, I could use some of the basic AT commands, to configure the hour, or the UART communication.

Now I'm trying to make a real wireless communication, but no matter what I try, I can't.
I tried using all the basic AT commands, in particular the ones that are for "scanning" bluetooth devices, or connecting via a serial number when the scanning finish, but it doesn't make anything at the UART console or at my cellphone (I tried to use an application at it called LightBlue to search for devices but it doesn't find the EMC3080-P).

Finally I tried to contact with the company assistant, but they are very short with the answers, and don't answer to the important questions I made.

I hope someone knows how to use it, meanwhile I will be trying to make it work in my way.